# how to deal with slow Ajax request / people with slow connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is a 'hypothetical' situation.

Let's say I have :
a websocket who tell's me to send a ajax on a url like `http://localhost/Whatever` every 10 sec.

The ajax call on `http://localhost/Whatever` will take 45 seconde to reply (exagerate number for the situation).

I wonder how will the browser react? in my mind 3 case:

1. (good one): Browser is really smart : He understand we ajax
   the same url so he won't stack ajax call until the current call
   finished.
2. Browser understand we ajax the same url and make an `abort()` on the
   Ajax 1st call and start a new one (if the browser really does that, it
   would be rubbish in my mind).
3. (worst case): Browser send a ajax on the url each time websocket ask
   him to and wait for the answer. Moreover, I suppose there will be a
   problem with limitation of parralel ajax request? (i wonder how the
   browser if this case happens ?)

So, Which case will happen and why ?

Comment: Which kind of behaviour do you prefer - [1] abort 1st request and start 2nd  or [2] wait for 1st request and call 2nd upon 1st end or [3] cancel 2nd request if 1st has not responded yet?

Comment: The browser does not do the first two automatically, your code (or the library you are using) has to implement those

Comment: @Miraage i prefer my first case for sure -> your [3]. but i supose as patrick Evans say that the third will be the default behaviour.

Comment: You could control how the browser reacts for each case. For example, in case one, you could set a variable when starting an ajax request that the browser checks before it does another request and just the variable back once the ajax call is done.

Comment: Case 3 is what will happen on a browser.  The AJAX request on the browser will eventually timeout on most browsers but the details of that are browser specific.  Using a library like jquery you can set a timeout in a cross browser way.

Comment: It can't be [2], it would be horrible. How does the browser know it's ok to cancel something just because the URL is the same? It has no idea what the server does. Meaning, maybe the first time an ajax method is called it does something, I don't know, like check the weather. The second time the same URL is called, it causes a database backup. A stupid example, but what stops me from writing code like that? [1] could work, but how does the browser know I don't want them to stack?  What if I'm doing an internet speed test and I want to do 5 calls to the same URL at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is case 3.

The browser will send all requests in the order you make them. Generally speaking a computer will carry out your instructions in the order your issue them. If you want or need special behavior such as throttling the rate of the requests or not sending the subsequent requests until prior ones have finished you will need to implement that your self.

Comment: He asked which and why. This doesn't answer why.

Comment: The why is "The browser will send all requests in the order you make them."

Comment: Thats what it is supposed to do. It would be a broken browser if it didn't

Comment: The why, I'm sure is in the spec. The "because it's supposed to" doesn't help people gain knowledge as to the reasoning behind it. If someone asks any question, you could always respond "because that's the way it works and it's broken if it doesn't." How does that share knowledge?

Comment: I would have though that it was common knowledge that if you issue an instruction to a computer it is supposed to carry out that instruction.

Comment: If I call function foo() I expect the computer to execute function foo. Do you think think further explanation is needed than the computer is supposed to carry out its instructions.

Comment: When one doesn't know what foo() does and the question is "how does foo work?" Absolutely!

Comment: but in this case we know that foo() is sendAjaxRequest() we know what it does. It sends an ajax request.

Comment: Obviously the op didn't or he wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, this pseudocode might help you.

```
var requestLock = false;

function pollFromSocket() {
  if (someCondition) {
    sendRequest();
  }
}

function sendRequest() {
  if (requestLock) {
    return;
  }

  requestLock = true;

  $.get('/whatever')
    .done(function(response) {
      // process response
    })
    .always(function() {
      requestLock = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: How? You need to explain this answer

Comment: I was thinking about this but using a array instead of boolean to retain the url , (to avoid because socket give many url in fact).
I secretly hope browser would do it by his own. Thank whenever

Comment: @ssbb, thats how we do. I just wrote *pseudocode*. Hope, it will help you.